# How can I create an automatically updated variable in Python 3+?

Tags: python, lambda

Code mock-up & expected results:

```
X = 10
Y = (X-10)/2
print(Y)
X = 12
print(Y)
```

I want this to print "0" and then "1", but obviously `Y` is not dynamically assigned.

I have tried utilizing lambda functions (a la `Y = lambda i: (X-10)/2)` to get this functionality, but I keep getting `<function <lambda> at 0x7f5f6356eea0>`.

This is just to avoid needing to run a function or redefine Y at the end of any function that alters the value of X.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you aware of SymPy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use properties as well:

```
class P:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return (self.__x - 10) / 2

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self.__x = x
```

You will have to access the values through an instance of the P class, though.

```
p = P(10)
print(p.y)
p.x = 12
print(p.y)
```

Comment: This is almost exactly how I intend for this to be used. I suspect I will need to rework the way my code looks right now to make this work, but this gives me something to read into. Thank you!

Comment: the example returns "AttributeError: can't set attribute" after fixing missing the init and class init

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried utilizing lambda functions (a la `Y = lambda i: (X-10)/2)`

You need to call the function:

```
print(Y())
```

As for having `print(Y)` print the updated value? Mostly impossible, and what workarounds exist aren't anywhere near worth it. Just be explicit about recomputing the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the lambda:

```
print(Y())
```

Assigning a lamda to a variable is essentially the same as defining a function:

```
def Y():
    return (X-10)/2
```

You can't do what you want with ordinary variables. Assigning a variable copies the value into it, it doesn't create a reference to the expression that was used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide **x** argument to your lambda function. In your case this is 10 or 12.

```
y = lambda x: (x-10)/2
print(y(10))

>>> 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign the value using your lambda expression, you need to call it. You can do it in **one line**:

```
Y = (lambda i: (i-10)/2)(X)
```

There is no need for defining additional classes or functions, just add the parentheses and the argument.

The reason you are getting `<function <lambda> at 0x7f5f6356eea0>` is that a lambda expression produces a function, not the result of executing the function.

Comment: This resolves the issue with not getting a response from print, at the very least.

`Y = (lambda i: (i-10)/2)(X)`

However this doesn't allow it to dynamically update the way I would like. Is there no way to get it to calculate each time the variable is called?

Comment: @Hyatice Really depends on how involved you expect your calculations to be. If it's just 2 variables, you could define `Y = lambda i: (i-10)/2` and get the corresponding value by calling `Y(X)`. If you expect to have more than 2 simple variables, look into using SymPy (the Python library for symbolic computation): http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html

Comment: @Hyatice Also, calling Y(X) is more explicit than having a magic variable that updates itself behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda with a dict to keep track of it:

```
>>> vars={}
>>> vars['x']=10
>>> vars['y']=lambda :(vars['x']-10.0)/2.0
>>> vars['y']()
0.0
>>> vars['x']=12.0
>>> vars['y']()
1.0
```